# failed to copy ...the specified network name is no longer available

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce

when i publish my app using Click Once Deployment i got this error:

> Failed to copy file 'D:\Tam Alsharq Operator - March 2013\Tam Alsharq
>   Operator (TAO)\Tam Alsharq Operator
>   (TAO)\bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\Tam Alsharq Operator
>   (TAO)_1_0_0_77\Tam Alsharq Operator (TAO).exe.deploy' to
>   '192.168.2.11\TAO\Application Files\Tam Alsharq Operator
>   (TAO)_1_0_0_77\Tam Alsharq Operator (TAO).exe.deploy'. Unable to add
>   'Application Files/Tam Alsharq Operator (TAO)_1_0_0_77/Tam Alsharq
>   Operator (TAO).exe.deploy' to the Web site.  Unable to add file
>   'Application Files\Tam Alsharq Operator (TAO)_1_0_0_77\Tam Alsharq
>   Operator (TAO).exe.deploy'.  The specified network name is no longer
>   available.

please help.!

Comment: The message is pretty clear - the target location isn't available. Either its not there anymore, or permissions, or a server problem is preventing access, that sort of thing. Is that IP still correct?

Comment: yes it's correct and i can access to it's resources easily, but when i ping @ it using Command prompt it gave "request timed out" A lot

Comment: You say the ping fails "A lot". Is that every time without exception, or does it sometimes return the ping successfully?

Comment: when i ping to server using -t it failed 3 times out of 10 and the rest of the 7 reply comes with big response time like 1200 ms at minimum

Comment: Are you on a company network? - sounds like you need to check that with your IT support folks. If packets are slow or being dropped (which they appear to be) there may be something wrong.

Comment: thanks Jon :) i guess that could be the problem i reported them waiting to their reply .... i am very grateful for help, no wonder you are from Manchester (am huge fan of United btw :D)

Comment: Added what we've discussed as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This issue will usually come down to either

- A missing location (check the IP and that the target location exists on the server)
- A permissions problem (check you hsve access to see/write to the target)
- An infrastructure issue - either server load causing the target to become unresponsive or network issues causing the operation to fail (check the ping if possible)

In your case you say that the ping is high and that some packets are lost, which might show a network config problem (I've seen duplicated IP address cause it for example) or even a network hardware failure (such as a bad switch or cable)

Its worth checking with your IT systems folks showing them the ping results to eliminate that as a possibility.