# WebListenerException:The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: c#, runtime-error, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There is an odd exception in logs of my `MVC 6 (beta 7)` project:

```
01:29:55.8657 Error Flush
System.IO.IOException ---> Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException: The specified network name is no longer available
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01:29:55.8901 Error ProcessRequestAsync
System.IO.IOException ---> Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException: The specified network name is no longer available
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.ResponseStream.FlushInternal(Boolean endOfRequest)
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.ResponseStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.Response.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.RequestContext.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

I have found such errors were outside the `MVC 6` ([the fist link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429439/specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-in-httplistener), [the second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425258/failed-to-copy-the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available))

But in my case a source of the exception is the `Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.ResponseStream.FlushInternal` method.

The error does not interrupt the application. It occurs after some queries (I did not notice a pattern), and is rarely.

Why this error occurs periodically in my log?

Can I do take any actions to avoid the error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the client disconnected before the response was sent. That can be difficult to detect without writing to the socket. We have a (private) work item to de-emphasize these error messages in the logs.